# Get hash keys from a multidimensional hash given partial key matches in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Newbie here. I am trying to get the first key from a hash of hashes.
Say I construct a hash of hashes like following:\

```
%hash;
$first_key;
$hash{'First'}{'Float'}=0.1;
$hash{'First'}{'XY'}='X0Y0';
$hash{'First'}{'Score'}=100;
```

I use

```
$hash{$_}{'Float'} eq 0.1 && $hash{$_}{'XY'} eq 'X0Y0'
    and $first_key = $_ for keys %hash;
```

to find the first key when there’s only one.
But how do I get an array or loop to get the first key if there is multiple matches with `$hash{$_}{'Float'} eq 0.1 && $hash{$_}{'XY'} eq 'X0Y0'`if there’s another set like the following:

```
$hash{'Second'}{'Float'}=0.1;
$hash{'Second'}{'XY'}='X0Y0';
$hash{'Second'}{'Score'}=90;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) to select from a list:

```
my @matching_keys = grep $hash{$_}{Float} == 0.1 && $hash{$_}{XY} eq 'X0Y0',
                    keys %hash;
```

You can use the same to select the first one:

```
my ($first) = grep ...
```

The parentheses are needed to keep `grep` in the list context, as in scalar context, it returns the number of matches. You can use a list subscript instead:

```
my $first = (grep ...)[0];
```

Alternatively, you can use `first` from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) which is not context sensitive:

```
use List::Util qw{ first };

my $first = first {
    $hash{$_}{Float} == 0.1 && $hash{$_}{XY} eq 'X0Y0'
} keys %hash;
```

Note that I used `eq` for strings, but `==` for numbers. For floats, even `==` can be tricky due to imprecision.

Comment: Isn't a hash inherently unordered? Is "first" meaningful here?

Comment: It's only meaningful if it's the only one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw{ first };

my %hash = (
            "First" => {
                        "Float" => "1",
                        "XY"    => "X0Y0",
                        "Score" => "100"
            },
            "Second" => {
                        "Float" => "0.1",
                        "XY"    => "X0Y0",
                        "Score" => "90"
            },
);
            
foreach my $key (keys %hash){
    if(($hash{$key}{"Float"} == 0.1) && ($hash{$key}{"XY"} eq 'X0Y0')){
        print "First Matched Key:$key";
        last;
    }   
}
```

Please Note:
Comparison operators (equal) for numbers and strings are achieved using `==` and `eq` respectively.